# How can I recover a electrum wallet with passphrase and keystore file?

Tags: electrum, wallet-recovery

Is there a way to recover a electrum wallet without the seed? I have the adress, passphrase and the wallet file. I tried restoring it but it asks for seed/ master key. I don't have those? Is there anything else I can try? When I load the file..it gives a unicode error. It looks like this. Is there a way to know, if this corrupted?

`楏ĸ滐막댁痡䋆篅㧟ᑺ铙ꋧ亿龏レ祯᧻檊�籅−⥷㳀⁼澀秴思緽쏹褪髊灒轣ꀠ垥�ﰘុ᝱缉疰ᘹ뮋戔〤ୠ紟糸綝⩵懼ݦ젗䲢墜賕派쭈ꑘ䗙�奲쯅Ს䫨꥓ሌ昗﮽ꯔፇ婤㹱䍈삗휶쨜⽐⭳暷ᢠ蘘᭩췛뻦庄`

I opened it in a hex editor to look for seed. There is no seed in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Is there a way to recover a electrum wallet without the seed?**

To recover the wallet you need either

- the password/passphrase of the wallet and **a good backup of the wallet**  or
- the **seed phrase** which is sometimes called a recovery phrase or backup phrase.

Since you have neither, you cannot recover the wallet.

Many scammers will contact you and offer to help, but they will just steal money from you.

---

It is sadly too late for you, but anyone else reading this should take note of the advice offered by user-guides for wallets like Electrum:

See  https://bitcoinelectrum.com/creating-an-electrum-wallet/

> **Before you begin**
>
> You will need to download and install electrum first. You can download it from here. If you are on Windows you should use the installer version and not the portable one.
>
> **You will need a pen and a notebook (recommended) or piece of paper to write down the seed mnemonic. The notebook will have to be kept somewhere safe** once you are done with the installation process so it can’t be a notebook that you use on a day to day basis.

...

> 5. Electrum displays the seed to you as a 12 word mnemonic. **It’s important at this stage to write down the seed in a notebook. You must put it down on paper.** Don’t keep it on your computer!

> Also write down “Software: Electrum” in your notebook below the seed mnemonic. You wouldn’t believe the number of users who forget what software they used!

(my emphasis)